# Foreign Key Types on Joins

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, inner-join, join, sqlperformance

I've read that when joining tables on FKs, the datatype of the column the join performed on affects performance.  For example, joining on `int` is faster than joining on `varchar(128)`  My question is, is that a true statement because joining on a field is faster based on the datatype or on the value within that datatype?

For example, if I do a join on the value of -2,147,483,648, is that faster than a join on the value of "J" because "J" takes up more space in the database, assuming "J" came from `varchar(128)` field?  Does a join on the value of 1 occur at the same speed as -2,147,483,648 if they both come from integer columns?

Comment: It is easy to test, isn't it? Just create two pairs of tables and use `int` in one and the very same values, but converted to `varchar(128)` in another.  Put few hundred million rows in each table and measure how long it takes to join them. Share your findings with us. I would expect `varchar` to be slower, but I have no idea how significant it would be. It should be at least proportional to the number of bytes that server has to read from the disk. All things equal, `varchar` uses more bytes than `int` or `smallint`, so it would be slower.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main factor in the performance of an equality comparison (that does not involve type casting or converting) is the size of the datatype. The integer types in SQL Server have fixed sizes (4 bytes for an `int`, 8 bytes for a `bigint`, etc. - refer to [the documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187745.aspx) for the full details), so the actual data is inconsequential. `Varchar`s, on the other hand (and as opposed to `char`s), vary in their size depending on the size of the data (see [the docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176089.aspx) for details), so having shorter data may indeed affect a query's performance, but you'll have to have a pretty large number of rows to notice any difference.